# Router renders nothing

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I copied store/Router solution from my previous project where it was working fine. Then updated redux/router/dom dependencies, made some changes, ex. deleted IndexRoute and used createBrowserHistory. In dev. tools it shows up that `Provider` component is rendered but it doesn't render any other component.

index.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    import Foo from './components/Foo ';
    import Bar from './components/Bar ';
    import Components from './components/App'
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import store, { history } from './store';

const router = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
          <Route exact path="/" exact component={Components.MainConnectedWithProps} />
          <Route exact path="/foo" component={Components.FooConnectedWithProps} />
          <Route exact path="/bar" component={Components.BarjkaConnectedWithProps} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
)

render(router, document.getElementById('root'));

//render(<Foo />, document.getElementById('root')); works just fine
```

App.js

```
  import * as actionCreators from '../actions/actionCreators' 
    import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
    import Main from './Main'
    import Foo from './Foo '
    import Bar from './Bar '
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'

function mapStateToProps(state) {
            return {
                     sampleData: state.sampleData
            }
        }
function mapDispachToProps(dispatch){
        return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
        }


export default {
    MainConnectedWithProps : connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispachToProps)(Main),
    FooConnectedWithProps: connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispachToProps)(Foo),
    BarConnectedWithProps: connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispachToProps)(Bar)
  }
```

store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import {syncHistoryWithStore} from 'react-router-redux'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

const defaultState = {
    sampleData: sampleData
}

const store = createStore(rootReducer, defaultState)
export const history = syncHistoryWithStore(createBrowserHistory(), store);
export default store;
```

package.json

```
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-redux": "^4.4.10",
"react-router": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8"
```

I'm pretty new to React so this might be some silly mistake. Thanks everyone in advance.

EDIT:
I created sandbox with main features - render many components on one "/" path and specific component with "/foo" or "/bar" paths using redux. It works just fine after changing `BrowserRouter` to `Router` with `history` object. https://codesandbox.io/s/old-dawn-spggs?file=/src/components/App.js

But when I try the same on VS Code it gives ***The prop location is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is undefined*** error for `Router history={history}` and no errors but renders nothing for `<BrowserRouter />`

EDIT 2: I used exacly the same history, react, redux dependencies verion as in codesandbox and it worked too in VS Code. But `Link` seems not to work now. When I type "/bar" manually it renders `Bar` but when I click on `Link path="/bar"`
it renders nothing.

EDIT 3: I took a closer look at links suggested in comments, and the solution is to downgrade `history` dependency to 4.7.1.

Also, is using this `MainConnectedWithProps`,`FooConnectedWithProps`...for every single component a good idea to pass props? I used to use `React.CloneElement` but I guess it's a not thing since `IndexRoute` is gone?

Comment: You might want to put this on codesandbox.io to make ot easier to diagnose

Comment: You don't want to use `BrowserRouter` if you're proving a history object - that's the default HTML5 implementation.

Comment: Hey, I created sandbox and it works fine. Can You please take a look at EDIT?

Comment: I never used `redux` bindings for `react-router` before so I can't say this for certain, but it looks like the package [is deprecated](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) and on top of that, the versions you have installed on the sandbox do not appear to be compatible. *This repo is for react-router-redux 4.x, which is only compatible with react-router 2.x and 3.x*. The linked github suggests using [connected-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router) instead.

Comment: Another note,  `react-router` v6 is vastly different than `v5`. It looks like you're previous project used `v5`. If you want to use the beta of `v6` then check out their migration guide here, https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/advanced-guides/migrating-5-to-6.md